# run javascript function from string variable and pass parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-callback

I need to call a user defined javascript function from within my costom jquery plugin and pass parameters to it, for example:

```
function test(data)
    {
      var myfunc="function(data){alert(data);}"; //this is user defined function I   retrieved from html tag attribute
      var fn=new Function("("+myfunc+")();");
      fn.apply(this,arguments);
      return fn;
} 
test("hello");
```

The result is undefined, how can I pass data parameter from test function to user defined function? thanks in advance!

question update:

I'm writing a jquery plugin to handle ajax request, much like asp.net mvc unobtrusive ajax, I get the ajax callfack function from html tag attrbute, for example:

```
<div data-ajax-success="function(data,status,xhr){alert(data);}"....
```

the value of data-ajax-success attribute is user defined function, it can be following formats:

```
data-ajax-success="function(data,status,xhr){alert(data);}"
data-ajax-success="function(data){alert(data);}"
data-ajax-success="function(){alert('hello');}"
data-ajax-success="functionName"
```

I need to parse this attribute value as javascript function and pass jquery ajax callback parameters to this function, where data-ajax-success value is function name, I could call it correctly using following method defined in Micrsoft jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js:

```
function getFunction(code, argNames) {
        var fn = window, parts = (code || "").split(".");
        while (fn && parts.length) {
            fn = fn[parts.shift()];
        }
        if (typeof (fn) === "function") {
            return fn;
        }
        argNames.push(code);
        return Function.constructor.apply(null, argNames);
    }
```

but when data-ajax-success is function body, I could not pass parameter to it, here's my sample  code that handle ajax callback:

```
loadData: function (index, options) {
complete: function (xhr,status) {
            $(context.loading).hide(context.loadingDuration);
            getFunction(context.onComplete, ["xhr", "status"]).apply(this, arguments);
            },
        success:function (data, status, xhr) {
            $(context.updateTarget).html(data);
            getFunction(context.onSuccess, ["data", "status", "xhr"]).apply(this, arguments);
            },
            error: getFunction(context.onFailure, ["xhr", "status", "error"])
});

      $.ajax(options);
  }
```

anyone can help me? thank you very much!

Comment: Can you explain more closely where the string `"function(data){alert(data);}"` comes from, exactly?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060634/jquery-string-to-function-convert) help? (Using `eval`)

Comment: Can I please be the first to point out that overall, this looks like a very bad idea and you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by modifying this microsoft method:

```
  function getFunction(code, argNames) {
    var fn = window, parts = (code || "").split(".");
    while (fn && parts.length) { fn = fn[parts.shift()]; }
    if (typeof (fn) === "function") { return fn; } //onSuccess="functionName"
    if ($.trim(code).toLowerCase().indexOf("function")==0) { return new Function("return (" + code + ").apply(this,arguments);");} //onSuccess="function(data){alert(data);}"
    argNames.push(code);
    try {return Function.constructor.apply(null, argNames); //onSuccess="alert('hello');return false;"
    }catch(e){alert("Error:\r\n"+code + "\r\nis not a valid callback function");}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MDN describes the syntax of the Function object like this:

```
new Function ([arg1[, arg2[, ... argN]],] functionBody)
```

Here is the corresponding example:

```
// Example can be run directly in your JavaScript console

// Create a function that takes two arguments and returns the sum of those arguments
var adder = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b");

// Call the function
adder(2, 6);
// > 8
```

Applied to your example code it should read:

```
var fn=new Function("data",myfunc);
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing an argument to the `fn` function.

Change this part:

```
var fn=new Function("("+myfunc+")();");
```

to this:

```
var fn=new Function("("+myfunc+")("+data+");");
```

But if you are defining the function like that the `data` variable must contain a json string:

```
var fn=new Function("("+myfunc+")("+JSON.stringify(data)+");");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not correctly using the Function constructor.  See this link for reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference%2FObjects%2FFunction#Example.3A_Specifying_arguments_with_the_Function_constructor

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Setting a default value to a function parameter.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function test(content)
    {
    const funString = `(function(content){return content})(content)`
    var adder = eval(funString);
   

// Call the function
return adder;
    
     
} 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test(2);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```